# How can i join columns from different worksheets using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

i'm trying to join a column with some data from one workbook to another workbook (excel), creating a new column, but i need to locate the data in a specific row. Both workbooks have a first column named "code", so if a code coincide with another, i need to join that data in a new column.

I've been doing that with pandas, using pd.merge(how="left"), but i need to do it with openpyxl, because it takes too long to download the excel as a dataframe instead of editing it with openpxl.

```
Resultados = pd.read_excel(destination_info, sheet_name='Resultado', header=0)
Carteras = pd.read_excel(destination_info, sheet_name='Cartera', header=0)
Carteras_compl = pd.read_excel(destination_info, sheet_name='Cartera Complemento', header=0)

Balances = Balances.rename(columns={'A':'Código'})
Resultados = Resultados.rename(columns={'A':'Código'})
Carteras = Carteras.rename(columns={'A':'Código'})
Carteras_compl = Carteras_compl.rename(columns={'A':'Código'})
Carteras = pd.concat([Carteras, Carteras_compl], axis=0)



activos = pd.read_excel(RUTA_INFO, sheet_name = 'Activos', header = 3)
      pasivos = pd.read_excel(RUTA_INFO, sheet_name = 'Pasivos', header = 3) 
      resultados = pd.read_excel(RUTA_INFO, sheet_name = 'Resultados', header = 3)
      complementos = pd.read_excel(RUTA_INFO, sheet_name = 'Información complementaria', header =3)

        activos = pd.merge(activos,Balances[['Código','B']],how= "left")
        pasivos = pd.merge(pasivos,Balances[['Código','B']],how= "left")
        resultados = pd.merge(resultados,Resultados[['Código','B']],how= "left")
        complementos = pd.merge(complementos,Carteras[['Código','B']],how= "left")

Thanks for your attention!
[wb1][1]


[wb2][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyw85.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWXun.png
```

Comment: Is it correctly understood that you have two workbooks (wb1, wb2) each of which have a sheet where the first column has the header "code" and if the "code" value for a given row is the same in both sheets then you want to copy all the data of that row from wb2 into wb1, placing it to the right of the columns that already exist on the row in wb1. Or do you want to append the information at the bottom of the list in wb1?

Comment: Hi, i have 2 wb with one common column "code" and i want to copy the data from wb1 to a new column in wb2, but with coincidences on the "code" value. I'm using pandas and opening the files with pd.ExcelFile and then excel.parse, but i want to know if i can run the code in less time. I will put the images of the wb's in the post.